# SpriteKit GameScene compatibility for ios7

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

My app runs well for iOS 8+ but iOS 7 mess up all the coordinates
what is the correct way to copy implementation of creation gameScene for ios 7

here is how i do it:

```
   if #available(iOS 8, *) {
    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        self.skView = self.view as! SKView

        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "quitToLevel:", name: "quitToLevelID", object:nil)
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
     } else {
        //here starts the wrong part
        if let scene = GameScene(size: view.frame.size) as GameScene? {

            let skView = self.view as! SKView

            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "quitToLevel:", name: "quitToLevelID", object:nil)
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: "sks") {
            var sceneData = try! NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
            var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

            archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
            let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! SKScene
            archiver.finishDecoding()
            return scene
        } else {
            return nil
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of it makes a difference but you should base the Scene size in the else statement on the skView.bounds.size

So change it to this

```
 } else {
    //here starts the wrong part
    let skView = view as! SKView!
    let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)

    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "quitToLevel:", name: "quitToLevelID", object:nil)

    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

and see if it works correctly now.

Not sure if this works on ios 7 but its worth a try. 
Do you need your app to support ios 7? There is only like 10% of the users left running that particular OS.

Comment: Hey, thank you I have already resolved it with an SKNode extension that i have posted on my comment

Comment: it says i can do it only tomorrow :(